# Jquery .post() not calling script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to pass the data from a form to an insertion script without having the form data cleared.  I am using this function to act on the press of the submit button but I get nothing.  It is even set to throw an error if the form is missing data but it doesn't even get that far.  I can only assume I am not calling it properly.

```
$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {
        var facility = $("#facility").val();
        var riskclient = $("#riskclient").val();
        var riskdate = $("#riskdate").val();
        var dataString = 'facitlity=' + facility + '&riskclient=' + riskclient + '&riskdate=' + riskdate;

        if (facility == '' || riskclient == '' || riskdate == '') {
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insertriskass.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(){
                    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="body">   
    <div align='center'>
        <div class="tablebackground">
            <form  method ="post" name= "form"  id="form">            
                <table border='1' >
                    <tr>
                        <td>Facility</>
                        <td><input  type="text" name= "riskFacility" id="facility"></td>
                        <td rowspan='4'><input type="submit" name="submit" value="New Client" class="submit"/</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Client</td>
                        <td><input required type="text" name="riskClientId" id="riskclient" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['riskClientId']); ?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Audit Date</td><td> <input required type="text" id="datepicker"     name="riskauddate" id="riskdate"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

It is definitely not passing anything to the insertion script. So again, I think I am calling it incorrectly.

Comment: you need a document.ready in there

Comment: have you checked the console. Ajax triggered or not?

Comment: does your page reload?

Comment: i think post method accept a json sting, not a url string, just replace 


`var dataString = 'facitlity='+ facility + '&riskclient=' + riskclient + '&riskdate=' + riskdate;` with `dataObject = {facility : facility , riskclient :  riskdate}` and use `data: JSON.stringify(dataObject )` instead of `data: dataString`

Comment: I tried your suggestions Hassan Nisar Khan but it didnt make a difference.

Comment: I tried your suggestions Hassan Nisar Khan but it didnt make a difference but console shows me there is a syntax error which I cant work out. ' $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insertriskass.php",
        // data: dataString,
       data: JSON.stringify(dataObject )
       success: function(){ ***this is where console shows syntax error
       $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
        $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
        }'

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan for the tidy up.  I applied it but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I see your html tags are not closed properly

```
<div class="body">
```

```
  <form method="post" name="form" id="form">

    <table border='1'>
      <tr>
        <td>Facility</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="riskFacility" id="facility">
        </td>
        <td rowspan='4'>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="New Client" class="submit" /> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Client</td>
        <td>
          <input required type="text" name="riskClientId" id="riskclient" value="">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Audit Date</td>
        <td>
          <input required type="text" id="datepicker" name="riskauddate" id="riskdate">
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </form>
```

and check if it comes to error call back

Comment: The event seems to be firing as I can use POST and print out its contents on that same page but its just being passed to the insertion script

Comment: Not being passed I should have said.   Is there something I should be putting on the called script that Im missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's useful..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#submit').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var facility = $("#facility").val();
var riskclient = $("#riskclient").val();
var riskdate = $("#riskdate").val();

var dataString = 'facitlity='+ facility + '&riskclient=' + riskclient + '&riskdate=' + riskdate; 
or 
// var datastring = $("#form").serialize();

if(facility=='' || riskclient=='' || riskdate=='' )
{
$('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "insertriskass.php",
data: dataString, 
success: function (msg) {
$('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
}
});
}
return false;
});
})
```

event.preventDefault used to stop submit and page reload.
datastring = $("#form").serialize(); used to submit all data values so no need to take each and every variable assign value.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor a little the code like this, revise your html tags. You have a double id property in an input, and missing clousure tags.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function(event) {
        event.PreventDefault();
        var facility = $("#facility").val();
        var riskclient = $("#riskclient").val();
        var riskdate = $("#riskdate").val();
        var dataString = 'facitlity=' + facility + '&riskclient=' + riskclient +    '&riskdate=' + riskdate;

        if (!facility || !riskclient || !riskdate) {
           $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
           $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
        } else {
           //send ajax post
        }
    });
});
```